# Select rows for which condition applies for multiple rows in long format with groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id_p': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4], 
              'id_d_b': [True, True, False, True, True, True,False,False,False], 
              'id_d_i': [False, False, True, False,False,False,True,True,True]})
foo

id_p    id_d_b  id_d_i
0   1   True    False
1   1   True    False
2   2   False   True
3   2   True    False
4   3   True    False
5   3   True    False
6   3   False   True
7   4   False   True
8   4   False   True
```

I would like to select the `id_p`s which has have **at least** one `True` at `id_d_b` `and` **at least** one `True` at `id_d_i`

I tried this

```
foo['id_d_b'] = foo['id_d_b'].astype(int)
foo['id_d_i'] = foo['id_d_i'].astype(int)

foo['has_id_d_b'] = foo.groupby('id_p')['id_d_b'].transform('max')
foo['has_id_d_i'] = foo.groupby('id_p')['id_d_i'].transform('max')

foo['result'] = foo['has_id_d_b'] + foo['has_id_d_i'] # if this is >1 then that specific id_p has at least one id_d_b and id_d_i
foo['result'] = foo.eval('result > 1')
foo

id_p    id_d_b  id_d_i  has_id_d_b  has_id_d_i  result
0   1   1   0   1   0   False
1   1   1   0   1   0   False
2   2   0   1   1   1   True
3   2   1   0   1   1   True
4   3   1   0   1   1   True
5   3   1   0   1   1   True
6   3   0   1   1   1   True
7   4   0   1   0   1   False
8   4   0   1   0   1   False
```

which gives the correct result, but I am looking for a "one-liner" solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: [`groupby.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) to check if any value per group is True, (eventually on a subset of columns), then ensure all columns are `True` with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html). With [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) you can get the relevant indices (for slicing or indexing if needed).

```
m = foo.groupby('id_p').any().all(axis=1)
# if other columns
# m = foo.groupby('id_p')[['id_d_b', 'id_d_i']].any().all(axis=1)

foo['result'] = foo['id_p'].isin(m[m].index)
```

For the indices:

```
print(m[m].index)
# Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64', name='id_p')
```

or, using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), which will be more expensive:

```
foo['result'] = foo.groupby('id_p').transform('any').all(axis=1)
# if other columns
# foo['result'] = this foo.groupby('id_p')[['id_d_b', 'id_d_i']].transform('any').all(axis=1)
```

output:

```
   id_p  id_d_b  id_d_i  result
0     1    True   False   False
1     1    True   False   False
2     2   False    True    True
3     2    True   False    True
4     3    True   False    True
5     3    True   False    True
6     3   False    True    True
7     4   False    True   False
8     4   False    True   False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` created by aggregate [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
foo['result'] = foo['id_p'].map(foo.groupby('id_p')[['id_d_b', 'id_d_i']].any().all(axis=1))
print (foo)
   id_p  id_d_b  id_d_i  result
0     1    True   False   False
1     1    True   False   False
2     2   False    True    True
3     2    True   False    True
4     3    True   False    True
5     3    True   False    True
6     3   False    True    True
7     4   False    True   False
8     4   False    True   False
```